# Tkinter check if a letter/word is getting deleted and highlight the replaced letter/word

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.6

So, I have a small program where you can find a string and highlight it, for example, you have the word: "ghazi" in the text field, in the find field I wrote "g", now it will highlight "g" in the text field, but if I deleted "g" from the find field and replaced it with "h" it highlights "gh" what I want is to the find method to highlight only the letter "h" since "g" is deleted from the entry box( find field).
I tried to check for entry field is empty so i can delete the highlight but it didnt work, here is the code:

```
  def Find(self):
        count=IntVar()
        s=self.text.search(self.entry.get(),'1.0',stopindex=END,count=count)
        self.text.tag_configure("match",background='yellow')
        end=f'{s}+{count.get()}c'
        self.text.tag_add("match",s,end)
        self.text.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event_data: self.text.tag_remove("match","1.0",END))
        if self.entry.get()==" ":
            self.text.tag_remove("match","1.0",END)
```

where `self.text` refer to Text() widget object.

Comment: We will need a bit more code than that to help you. Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @j_4321 added the full code of find method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why both letters are highlighted is because you do not remove the "match" tag from the "g", you only add it to the "h". So if you have not clicked in the text widget, the highlight stays on the "g". So your `Find()` function should start with `self.text.tag_remove("match", "1.0", END)`.

You can also improve other things in your code:

1. I would check if the entry is empty and, if so do not perform the search:

   ```
   if not self.entry.get().strip():
       return
   # ... do the search
   ```
2. No need to configure the "match" tag every time you run `Find()`, just do it once when you create `self.text`.
3. Same thing for the binding to `<Button-1>`

Here is a full example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
count = tk.IntVar(root)
entry = ttk.Entry(root)

text = tk.Text(root)
text.tag_configure('match', background='yellow') 
text.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event_data: text.tag_remove("match", "1.0", tk.END))

def find():
    text.tag_remove("match", "1.0", tk.END)  # clear highlights
    string = entry.get()
    if not string.strip():  # entry contains only spaces:
        return

    s = text.search(string, '1.0', stopindex=tk.END, count=count)
    end = f'{s}+{count.get()}c'
    text.tag_add("match", s, end)

button = ttk.Button(root, text='Find', command=find)

text.pack()
entry.pack()
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, yes i realized that adding tag_remove() at the beginning of the function will remove the highlight because each time i press "Find" button it does call the Find() method which will remove the previous highlight firstly then go in, thanks for code improvement suggestion also :)